# Put controller variable to href attribute

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

I have a variable in my Sinatra application:

```
 get '/' do
    @agenda_date    = Date.today
    @next_date_str  = (Date.today + 1).to_s
    @prev_date_str  = 'date=' + (Date.today - 1).to_s
```

And I want use it as href attribute in my view:

```
%a{:id => 'prev_day', :href => @prev_date_str } Prev day
```

or

```
%a{:id => 'prev_day', :href => 'date=' + @next_date_str } Next day
```

How can I get it?

Comment: What you have written works fine. Are you seeing an error message? No content in your output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
%a{:id => 'prev_day', :href => "date=#{@next_date_str}" }
```

If that's what you ask...

First line works as it is, so I'm not sure what issue do you have? Only thing missing in the handler is

```
haml :view_name
```